# Linear Equation not possible to solve?

Tags: r, linear-equation

I want to solve a linear equation A*x=b with

```
A<-matrix(c(1,4,9,5,2,3,8,4,3,2,7,3,4,1,6,2),4,4)
b<-c(2,0,7,9)
```

If I then use the solve() function it shows an error:

```
solve(A,b)
Error in solve.default(A, b) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.06241e-18
```

Is there any fault in my approach or is this linear equation not possible to solve?

Comment: Your matrix has a 0 determinant (`det(A)`) and thus can not find the inverse, hence the singularity error

Comment: Thanks! So, it is not possible to solve it, right? Or is there any other way? @Sotos

Comment: No, you can't invert a singular matrix. I am not sure If you can use linear algebra to make it non-singular. My math is a bit rusty

Comment: If `det(A)` is 0 there is no unique solution to your linear system. Then two cases are possible: a) there is no solution b) there are infinite many solution. Case a) or b) depend on the vector b. If vector b is element of span(A) then it is case b) otherwise case a).

Answer (score 1):

There are some linear relationships between the columns of `A`:

```
> A <- matrix(c(1,4,9,5,2,3,8,4,3,2,7,3,4,1,6,2),4,4)
> # linear relationship between columnds 2,4,3:
> A[,2] + A[,4]
[1]  6  4 14  6
> 2 * A[,3]
[1]  6  4 14  6
> # linear relationship between columnds 1,3,2:
> A[,1] + A[,3]
[1]  4  6 16  8
> 2 * A[,2]
[1]  4  6 16  8
```

Therefore, `A` is not invertible.